# Why first page load is slow with ASP.MVC + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an application with ASP.NET MVC and AngularJS.
My route are manage by AngularJS with `ui-router`.

The first time AngularJS load the partialview it's more slow then the second. What causes this ?

There are my codes:

**AngularJS**

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    var homeState = {
        name: 'home',
        url:'/home',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        controllerAs:'vm',
        templateUrl:'/AngularJS/Home/Home'   //AngularJS is a Area/Controler/Method
    }
    var loginState = {
        name: 'login',
        url: '/login',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: '/AngularJS/Home/Login'
    }
    var registrationState = {
        name: 'registration',
        url: '/registration',
        controller: 'RegistrationCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: '/AngularJS/Home/Registration'
    }
    var dashboardState = {
        name: 'dashboard',
        url: '/dashboard',
        controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        templateUrl: '/AngularJS/Home/Dashboard'
    }

... 
    $stateProvider.state(homeState);
    $stateProvider.state(loginState);
    $stateProvider.state(registrationState);
    $stateProvider.state(dashboardState);
    $stateProvider.state(gameState);
    $stateProvider.state(userState);
    $stateProvider.state(newGameState);
    $stateProvider.state(platformState);
    $stateProvider.state(unavailabilityState);
    $stateProvider.state(teamsState);
    $stateProvider.state(newTeamState);
    $stateProvider.state(editTeamState);
    $stateProvider.state(detailTeamState);

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(requestInterceptor);


})
```

**ASP.NET MVC**

```
public PartialViewResult Home()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home";
            return PartialView();
        }
        public PartialViewResult Login()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Login";
           return PartialView();
        }
        public PartialViewResult Registration()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Registration";
            return PartialView();
        }

        public PartialViewResult Dashboard()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
            return PartialView();
        }

...
```

Exemple load time:
First
[image]

Second[image]

Comment: Try using the network profiler on google chrome to check which resource is taking time to load up

Comment: @Laazo I have added picture from network profiler.

Answer (score 0):

application might be trying to load large resource that you have added to template, one way of find it is using Chrome browser (it also available in other browsers as well)  follow bellow steps,

right click on the page go to Inspect element and select Network tab as bellow.
[image]

there you can see the time that took to load each resources , when its getting higher , site will take more time to load

Comment: First time when i load my page games: 2,65s. (Request GetAll 533ms) Second time 53ms (page + request). I don't kwon why i don't see my page  in network google. Have this with all page first time. No jjust with game page.

Comment: @nevradub Normally when we running a application , it loads all the resources (css,js,images) that is why it takes 2.6 seconds  but if u refresh, it not gonna load all the files because most of files are cashing,

as a solution try to minimize the java script files and optimize the Image's  quality as you required 
hope this will helps

Comment: Yes i know but isn't all ressource when i execute my application. There is just when i change page from Dashboard to Games for exemple. All ressource (js / img / css) is already loaded at the moment. 2.65 second for get xhr from server to client. This isn't normal.

Comment: @nevradub I didn't get your above comment, please explain

Comment: If you look my two print screen you watch time of request xhr for load my page games. It's after loading all ressource of my app.

Comment: @nevradub as I explained earlier, we loading all the resources at the first time of execution, then we load the simple partial views, and most of time application will taking longer time to load resources and less time to load partial views,
but there are some certain scenarios that partial views might get longer time than the first execution, and It depend on the contents of partial view, (ex: there might have large files reference in the partial view)
or may be a issue of a function,
we cant really decide it without checking the code, try to check everything  from top to bottom again